# A traceback error occurs while reading a CSV File

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, traceback

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('/content/Glassdoor Reviews.csv', encoding='latin1',error_bad_lines=False,sep=';')
df.head()

nullcheck=df.isnull().sum()
print(nullcheck)

count=df['Category'].value_counts()
print(count)

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X = df['Review']  # this time we want to look at the text
y = df['Category']
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=20)
```

```
                   ERROR
```

### `
Category,Review,Remarks    0
dtype: int64
b'Skipping line 170: expected 1 fields, saw 2\n'

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
2645             try:
-> 2646                 return self._engine.get_loc(key)
2647             except KeyError:

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

KeyError: 'Category'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
2 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
2646                 return self._engine.get_loc(key)
2647             except KeyError:
-> 2648                 return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))
2649         indexer = self.get_indexer([key], method=method, tolerance=tolerance)
2650         if indexer.ndim > 1 or indexer.size > 1:

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

KeyError: 'Category'
`

Comment: Maybe you have two `;` in you first line, and only one in the rest.

Comment: What is line 169 / 170 / 171 ?

Comment: @Mike67: The dataset has only Category, Review and Remarks columns while the coding has only 57 lines

Comment: Puzzling. How is it skipping line 170 with only 57 lines in the file?  You may have a newline issue where the newline is not appearing in your text editor (Windows requires \r\n to appear). Try viewing in a different editor (or different settings). You can also post the file\data so we can check it.

Comment: @Mike67: This works well on Spyder(offline). When i paste the same code on an online compiler i get the above error....

Comment: Before opening the file as a CSV, open the file as text and get the length. Compare the lengths in each environment.